# Is there a way to add a theme to non-core material-ui components?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am using the data-grid and the date-picker from material-ui and I wish to change their theme with `createMuiTheme`. The issue is that the current `ThemeOptions` does not include either component's classnames. Is there an actual way to add those themes?

I am using `@material-ui/core@4.11.2`, `@material-ui/data-grid@4.0.0-alpha.57` `@material-ui/pickers@3.2.2` and `typescript@4.2.4`

Comment: `does not include either component's classnames` what do you mean? Maybe it will be better if you can create a codesandbox which demonstrate what you want achieve..

Comment: In the `createMuiTheme` it has the `ThemeOptions` interface and it includes only the core's components.